# connecting to LDAP server using php

Tags: php, ldap, domaincontroller

I want to connect to a LDAP server to get a list of OUs using php.

```
    $ldaphost = "ldap://192.168.10.10";
    $ldapUsername  = "ldap_user";
    $ldapPassword = "xxxxxxxx";

    $ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost);

    if(!ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)){
        print "Could not set LDAPv3\r\n";
    }
    else if (!ldap_start_tls($ds)) {
        print "Could not start secure TLS connection";
    } 
    else {
    // binding to the ldap server
        $bth = ldap_bind($ds, $ldapUsername, $ldapPassword) or die("\r\nCould not connect to LDAP server\r\n");
    }
```

After running the code, I get the following error:

```
LDAP_START_TLS(): UNABLE TO START TLS: SERVER IS UNAVAILABLE
```

I don't know if either anything wrong with my code or any problem with server configuration!? However, I could connect to server through AdExplorer with the same LDAP username and password.

Comment: Another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689629/how-do-i-solve-ldap-start-tls-unable-to-start-tls-connect-error-in-php

Comment: One more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817876/how-to-perform-a-ldap-sasl-bind-to-active-directory-using-gss-api-mech-in-php-fr